# How to create alert after taking picture using camera in swift

Tags: swift, camera, alert

I have one button when i taped the button camera on and take the pictures.after taking the picture i need to show the alert to the user.the alert section not working.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/leGRT.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is working for me, i am able to resolve my issue.

```
func cameraAsscessRequest() {
        if AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatus(for: AVMediaType.video) ==  AVAuthorizationStatus.authorized {

    } else {
        AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(for: AVMediaType.video) { granted -> Void in

        }
    }
}

func image(){

    if !UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera){
        let alertController = UIAlertController.init(title: nil, message: "Device has no camera.", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let okAction = UIAlertAction.init(title: "Alright", style: .default, handler: {(alert: UIAlertAction!) in
        })
        alertController.addAction(okAction)
        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    else{
        //other action
        imagePicker.sourceType = .camera
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
        self.present(imagePicker,animated: true,completion: nil)
    }



}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
   if let pickedimage =     info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as?UIImage{
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "",
                                  message: "Are you sure you want to upload invoice ?",
                                  preferredStyle: .alert)

    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default) {
        UIAlertAction in
        Print("Camera On")

    }
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel) {
        UIAlertAction in
        print("lll")
    }


    alert.addAction(cancelAction)
    alert.addAction(okAction)

    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this you need to swizzle the AlertController's present method and then present your own, forward the user input to the original alert. I wouldn't prefer this anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line after adding action:

```
self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not getting why you want to do this type of functionality.If you really want to achieve this write code for alertcontroller creating and presenting inside the dissmiss method handler of imagePicker delegate method. Simple when you got image it will show alert.

You can try like this:

```
 func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController!, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: NSDictionary!) {
    let selectedImage : UIImage = image
   //var tempImage:UIImage = editingInfo[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as UIImage
    img.image=selectedImage
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion:{ () void -> in

DispatchQueue.main.async {
let alert = UIAlertController(title: title,
                                  message: message,
                                  preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK",
                                     style: .cancel, handler: nil)

    alert.addAction(cancelAction)
    //vc will be the view controller on which you will present your alert as you cannot use self because this method is static.
    vc.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
 }

})    
 }
```

Comment: Hi javed Thanks for your quick reply i'm adding  the  alert inside of the delegate method only but its not working.i'm using   Following  delegate method   func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController!, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: NSDictionary!)

Comment: Can you try please above mentioned code @N.DharaniKumar

Comment: You can also try to show alert after few seconds when dissmiss image picker.